# How to guarantee data dependence with atomic?

Tags: c++

How to guarantee data dependence with c++ atomic?

I want to add something into map in muti-thread, I use atomic_uint64_t for indicator.
In every add step,the indicator++.

```
atomic_uint64_t id;
id.fetch_add(1,memory_order_relaxed);
map[id] = "something";
```

How can I guarantee the id in `map[id]="something"` is the same as the result of `id.fetch_add`.

Comment: This code fragment is too short for the purpose. If this would be in a simple function `void foo(std::map<uint64_t, std::string>& map)` then there's no risk at all. Each function call would then have its own `id`, and there would be no point in making it atomic. So clearly context matters.

Comment: yes,the type of map_ is `std::map<uint64_t, std::string>& map`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

The atomicity of `id` doesn't prevent some other thread from increasing the value between your `fetch_add` call and `map[id]` assignment/insertion.

Use a [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to protect the whole section instead.

By using a mutex, you also prevent data-races for the map access as well.

Comment: In this particular case: can't the return value of `fetch_add` be used in some way? If i read it correctly, the value returned is the value before adding 1.

Comment: @Caramiriel: Of course, that's the whole point of the `fetch` part.

Comment: @Caramiriel Of course you could do that, but then comes the problem of possible data-races for the map itself. Even if the key is different, two threads attempting to insert a value simultaneously will lead to problems.

Comment: how about like this:```auto id_current =  id.fetch_add(1,memory_order_relaxed);map[id_current] = "something";```

Comment: @Ds.Hale: That still won't work. For example, assume that the map is empty at the start, and internally structured as a tree. Two threads may both decide to create the root node, but obviously there can only be one root node in a tree. That is why you need a mutex. One thread will be blocked, and when it does get to run it will find that the map is no longer empty.